# Could you prove that $f(A) \geq 0$ whenever $A>0$?

Tags: matrices, polynomials

$A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix. $A$ is called positive, denoted $A>0$, if every entry of $A$ is positive. Similarly we can define $A \geq 0$. Let

$$f(x)=x^6+x^4-x^3+x^2+x$$

Could you prove that $f(A) \geq 0$ whenever $A>0$?

I have tried many matrices on CAS, it is true. But I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible strategies are to prove that $A^4-A^3+A^2\ge0$ always (since $A^6+A>0$ trivially) or even to prove that $A^2-A+I\ge0$ always (since multiplying by $A^2$ preserves that). Have you tested these statements to see if they're plausible? Presumably they'd be simpler to prove.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. For example, check that it fails for a nonnegative matrix, say $$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&2&0\\2&0&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right].$$ Then perturb $A$ to make it a matrix with positive entries. By continuity, this gives a counterexample.

Comment: But the condition is $A > 0$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan See the last two sentences. For example, replace each $0$ with $0.01$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your counterexample!